# DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator job failed in Cloud Composer without reasons

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to trigger a dataflow job in Cloud Composer using DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator (DataflowTemplateOperator cannot open the template file because it is too big). The task ran and failed without throwing an error. This is the task's code:

```
default_args = {
    # Tell airflow to start one day ago, so that it runs as soon as you upload it
    "start_date": days_ago(1),
    "dataflow_default_options": {
        "project": project_id,
        # Set to your region
        "region": gce_region,
        # Set to your zone
        "zone": gce_zone,
        # This is a subfolder for storing temporary files, like the staged pipeline job.
        "temp_location": bucket_path + "/tmp/",
    },
}

# Define a DAG (directed acyclic graph) of tasks.
# Any task you create within the context manager is automatically added to the
# DAG object.
with models.DAG(
    # The id you will see in the DAG airflow page
    "composer_dataflow_dag",
    default_args=default_args,
    # The interval with which to schedule the DAG
    schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),  # Override to match your needs
) as dag:
    create_mastertable = DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator(
        task_id="create_mastertable",
        py_file=f'gs://bucket/dags/pipeline_jobs/template_mastertable.py',
        py_options=[],
        job_name='{{task.task_id}}',
        options={
            "output": 'projectid:datasetid.table'
        },
        py_requirements=['apache-beam[gcp]==2.25.0', 'pandas', 'numpy', 'google-cloud-storage==1.33.0', 'google-cloud-bigquery==1.28.0', 'pyarrow==1.0.1', 'fsspec==0.8.4', 'geopy~=1.21.0'],
        py_interpreter='python3',
        py_system_site_packages=False,
        location='europe-west4',
        wait_until_finished=False,
    )
    create_mastertable
```

I put the dataflow script under the `dags` folder on GCS bucket per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210787/import-error-python-dataflow-job-in-cloud-composer) but it did not work.

There was no error being thrown but the task still failed. This is the last log of the task:

```
[2021-04-13 07:27:49,488] {beam.py:94} INFO - Running command: /tmp/apache-beam-venvv0vn6s8c/bin/python /tmp/tmprgudebwttemplate_mastertable.py --runner=DataflowRunner --project=project-id --region=europe-west4 --zone=europe-west1-b --temp_location=gs:///tmp/ --job_name=create-mastertable-9aa14c9d --output=projectid:datasetid.table --labels=airflow-version=v1-10-12-composer
```

I ran the dataflow script successfully locally using `DirectRunner`. Because the script itself is heavy and the task takes time, there can be an TimeOutError, but I'm not sure if that's the cause or how to solve it.

Comment: Did you check the logs in Dataflow? The job should have appeared in Dataflow since composer used  `--runner=DataflowRunner`.

Comment: Hi Ricco, I checked and there weren't any job in Dataflow

Comment: You can try reaching out to [GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for this to be checked.